# Which graphicsmagick delegate to use for .bmp files

Tags: graphicsmagick

I'm using linux distro and according to http://www.graphicsmagick.org/README.html#add-on-libraries-programs, there are libraries to support other image formats like jpg,png,etc.

According to http://www.graphicsmagick.org/formats.html, bmp files are supported in graphicsmagick.

But does anyone know which delegate library to use for bitmap(.bmp) files ?

Answer (score 2):

BMP support is built into GraphicsMagick.  No add-on library is required.